# Google Document AI with gs:// URI results in 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Document bytes or path is required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am facing `3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Document bytes or path is required` error while using Google Cloud Document AI with `gs://`file URI.

**Minimal implementation on node.js 12**

```js
const documentai = require('@google-cloud/documentai').v1;
function processingDocument(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let options = {
            credentials: {
                client_email: client_email,
                private_key: private_key,
            },
            projectId: project_id
        };
        const client = new documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(options);
        client.processDocument(params, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            };
            return resolve(true); // Testing only
        })
    })
};
```

`params` that works:

```json
const params = {
   "name":"projects/project_name/locations/us/processors/xxxx",
   "rawDocument":{
      "mimeType":"image/png",
      "content":"iV....=" //b64 content
   }
}
```

`params` that does **not** work

```json
const params = {
   "name":"projects/project_name/locations/us/processors/xxxx",
   "inlineDocument":{
      "mimeType":"image/png",
      "uri":"gs://bucket_name/demo-assets/file.png"
   }
}
```

I thought about a permission error, I checked whether Document AI required explicit permission to Google Storage, apparently not.

Tried also with a more elaborated payload

```json
const params = {
   "name":"projects/project_name/locations/us/processors/xxxx",
   "inlineDocument":{
      "mimeType":"image/png",
      "textStyles":[
         
      ],
      "pages":[
         
      ],
      "entities":[
         
      ],
      "entityRelations":[
         
      ],
      "textChanges":[
         
      ],
      "revisions":[
         
      ],
      "uri":"gs://bucket_name/demo-assets/file.png"
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am stuck. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uri` field cannot currently be used for processing a document.

You are currently using Online Processing, which only supports local files.

If you want to process documents stored in Google Cloud Storage, you will need to use Batch Processing following the examples provided on this page.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process

The GCS Input URI must be provided in the [`BatchDocumentsInputConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/BatchDocumentsInputConfig) `gcsPrefix` or `gcsDocuments` field.